# Expanding partition on SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, storage

I have recently bought an SSD and I am getting ready to clone my windows partition and such.

The partition I wish to clone is smaller than the size of the SSD, So if I expand the partition will I screw anything up like the partition alignment or allocation size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like `dd` or `dd_rescue` from the Linux command line to clone the partition (or drive) bit for bit.  It will not screw any of the structure up since it is essentially making a mirror image of the drive.  The only other advice I can give is to be careful when you clone the drive so you don't destroy any of your data.

Once the disk is cloned just use something like [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to expand the drive to use the maximum amount of space.